# cURL works where Fetch fails with error 422

Tags: javascript, curl, fetch-api

Got a small app that makes API requests for verification to an external endpoint, which has worked up until now.

The cURL request is as follows:

```
curl https://api.gumroad.com/v2/licenses/verify \
  -d "product_permalink=PRODUCT_PERMALINK" \
  -d "license_key=INSERT_LICENSE_KEY" \
  -X POST
```

And returns a `success` response.

Turning that into a `Fetch` request returns `Error 422`. I'm using `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`, as it otherwise gets blocked by CORS policy. The request is as follows:

```
fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.gumroad.com/v2/licenses/verify", {
  body: "product_permalink=SCpVP&license_key=INSERT_LICENSE_KEY",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  method: "POST"
})
```

This used to work, but it suddenly does not. The response error is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`, which I don't quite understand.

How would I fix my fetch request to work, much like the cURL request?

Comment: _“which I don't quite understand”_ - instead of JSON, you likely got an HTML document returned together with that status code - so something that begins with `<…`, which is obviously _not_ valid JSON. Check what the response body actually contained in the network panel, maybe there is a human readable error message in there.

Comment: @CBroe It does indeed return an HTML document. I just don't quite understand why I'm getting a 422 error on the Fetch request, but not on cURL.

Comment: I was using `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`. Could that be the culprit?

Comment: If we add no-cors we get 422 so it is likely your client is not allowed to fetch from that server - specifically cors-anywhere could be blocked. Use your own proxy then

Comment: Oh, so the code you posted is NOT the code you are having an issue with

Comment: The code you now posted (with the correct credentials) works just fine

Comment: but, the code you've shown won't ever have a problem if the response is NOT valid JSON, either ... do you have a `.then(resp => resp.json())` in your code?

Comment: I do, but the response is `422 (Unprocessable Entity)` on that request.

Comment: odd, since it doesn't happen to me when using the credentials you originally posted

Comment: I do get 422 too

Answer (score 1):

You might have been getting rate limited. As [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/)'s readme says,

> This server is only provided so that you can easily and quickly try out CORS Anywhere. To ensure that the service stays available to everyone, the number of requests per period is limited, except for requests from some explicitly whitelisted origins.

> If you expect lots of traffic, please host your own instance of CORS Anywhere, and make sure that the CORS Anywhere server only whitelists your site to prevent others from using your instance of CORS Anywhere as an open proxy.

Using your code still wouldn't work for me though— I kept getting an error message that there weren't any products for the permalink I'd supplied.

However, this code from [Ed](https://uhded.com/gumroad-payment-chrome-extension) works perfectly fine, if you combine it with cors-anywhere:

```
fetch("http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.gumroad.com/v2/licenses/verify", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        product_permalink: "<YOUR-PERMALINK>",
        license_key: "<YOUR-LICENSE—KEY>",
        increment_uses_count: false,
      }),
    })
```